# Glmer Time labeling

Tags: r

I already created a library project with the data saved there (imported excel).
Planned is a binary log Regression with repeated measures (data is in long format). Since measures happened at time1,2 an 3 I only want to take a look at 2 and 3.

My prof told me to enter;

```
Install.packages(“lme4”)

library(readxl)
d=read_xlsx.(“DS-AKT”)
d=as.data.frame(d)

d$Pandemia = factor(d$Time, levels=1:3, labels=c("Before", "During", "After"))
```

In order to recode the times 1,2,3 to before, during and after.

So my data is DS-AKT(excel file) and the times 1,2,3 are in die variable named “Pandemia”.

First Problem here says: `error in ‘$<-.data.frame’(*tmp*,pandemia, value=integer(0)):`
And that the input has 0 row while the data has 1126.

What exactly is the problem here? The variables value is set but to numeric not time, is that why?

Comment: Are you sure that there is a variable called `Time` , including the uppercase `T`.  (e.g. can reproduce the error by trying to use a variable `Time` that is not present in `mtcars` : `mtcars$Pandemia <- factor(mtcars$Time, levels=1:3, labels=c("Before", "During", "After"))`)

Comment: You say that "*times 1,2,3 are in die variable named “Pandemia”.*" but you then use `d$Time`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the probleme would need just to specify in your command the number of time you would like to get each row repeated. For example I had a kind similar problem in specify the number of time I wanted to add to my dataset rows for TIME variable, that has been added subsequently to get the whole data to work on and I did like this:

```
df_join <- data %>% 
  add_row(data1) %>% #this was for merge together the three datasets I had beforehand separated
  add_row(data2) %>%
arrange (ID)%>% #
  mutate(time = rep.int(c('t1', 't2', 't3'), 25))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the basic problem here is that (as @user20650 suggests) you have `Pandemia` and `Time` switched: `Pandemia` is the variable you have and `Time` is the one you want to create, but your code has it the other way around.

Example:

```r
d <- data.frame(Pandemia = 1:3)
factor(d$Time, levels=1:3, labels=c("Before", "During", "After"))
```

This produces `factor(0)`; that is, an empty (length-0) factor variable (because `d$Time` is `NULL`, that is, there is no `Time` variable in the data frame `d`).

If we try to assign the result back to the data frame, we get the error you saw:

```r
d$Pandemia <- factor(d$Time, levels=1:3, labels=c("Before", "During", "After"))
```

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Pandemia, value = integer(0)) :
> replacement has 0 rows, data has 3

On the other hand, if we do it the right way around:

```r
d$Time <- factor(d$Pandemia, levels=1:3, labels=c("Before", "During", "After"))
```

then we get

```r
  Pandemia   Time
1        1 Before
2        2 During
3        3  After
```

Comment: Thanks yes that definitely was the problem here. I ended up opting to rewrite the time variable.

Comment: If this solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...